# Convert String to Set[int] using delimiter in scala

Tags: scala

I have a string e.g. "100,123,124" and wanted to convert into Set[Int] data type. e.g Set[100,123,124]

How to convert this in Scala?

Answer (score 3):

Simply use:

```
"100,123,124".split(",").map(_.toInt).toSet
```